# What's the main difference between account and organization,collection in Azure DevOps?

Tags: tfs, azure-devops

I have worked with TFS for server years. We will move to Azure DevOps in next month.

After go through some docs, got some questions in below:

1. Why we call an organization for a url not account?
2. Why Azure DevOps only have one collection (default collection) unlike TFS server?
3. If one organization corresponding to one collection, when we move TFS to Azure DevOps, do we have to create multiple organizations for multiple collections?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a problem left over by history, some old docs/blogs may not updated timely.

For example, in documentation:

To sign in to your Azure DevOps account at any time, go to *https://{youraccount}.visualstudio.com.*

… should become:

To sign in to your AzureDevOps organization at any time, go to *https://{yourorganization}.visualstudio.com*

This change  rolled out with our [Sprint 137 Update](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/release-notes/2018/jul-10-vsts):

> **Adopt the word "organization" when referring to a collection of projects in Azure DevOps**
>
> We've made a change to our terminology when it comes to referring to a
>   collection of projects in Azure DevOPS.
>
> Previously we used the term "account" but have found that this has
>   caused a lot of confusion for the broader developer and open source
>   community. We've chosen to replace the term "account" with
>   "organization". You'll start seeing this change roll out in
>   documentation and in-product with this Update.

You account could create or be added in multiple organizations, for example:

[image]

As for moving TFS to Azure DevOps, create multiple organizations or not, it's based on your company's need. We suggest to do this if you use **TFS Database Import Service**

> It provides a high fidelity way to migrate collection databases from
>   Team Foundation Server (TFS) to Azure DevOps Services. It's
>   recommended that you download the [migration guide](https://azure.microsoft.com/zh-cn/services/devops/migrate/) if you're
>   looking to use this service to import your collection(s).
>
> The guide
>   serves as a walk through of the different steps involved in an import.
>   Providing best practices, checklists, and helpful tips to make your
>   import as easy as possible. The guide should be used in conjunction
>   with the more technical documentation referenced below to successfully
>   import to Azure DevOps Services.

Comment: I am new to Azure DevOps, and this is very frustrating to me.  At a minimum, ADO needs to have a terminology page to inform users because the documentation uses terms interchangeably unbeknownst to the reader.